# Xamarin Forms - Complex ListView or CollectionView implementation

Tags: listview, user-interface, xamarin.forms, binding, collectionview

I have a Xamarin forms application and want to create a complex screen but I really don't know how to do that. The image below shows what I want to create.

[image]

How can I achieve this using Xamarin forms. Should I use listviews for this, collection views or something else? As you can see, each cell/block is different, even the first one starting with 1234 14-rt-gk is very different.

Comment: As of now, I think you should use CollectionView it well performant has good documentation and easy to use!   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of ListView. You can make DataTemplates and also a DataTemplateSelector. What the DataTemplateSelector does is it choose the DataTemplate in runtime based on a particular value. 
That is the only way to achieve this. I will share a link for DataTemplateSelector Implementation.

Link 1:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Link 2:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/templates-datatemplateselector/

Comment: thanks for your help. Is it also needed to use custom controls? Or should I just make use of the components you named?

Comment: You need to make data templates. I would make 2 data templates for this. One without yellow part and one with yellow part. And then use a data template selector to select the template in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but I have done this before by creating a view cell template with databinding and a listview.

In your ContentPage.cs:

```
MyListView.ItemsSource = MyObjectCollection;
```

In your ContentPage.xaml bind your object properties to the viewCell properties:

```
 <ListView>
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <MyViewCell x:Name="MyViewCellName">
                                 ImageHeight="{Binding ImageHeight}"
                                 ImageWidth ="{Binding ImageWidth}"
                                 AuthorPicture="{Binding AuthorPicture}" 
                                 Author="{Binding Username}"

                    </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

Viewcell.cs declare your bindable properties, add accessor methods and build your components in the constructor:

```
    public class MyViewCell: ViewCell {
        Image MediaImage;
        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageHeightProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ImageHeight", typeof(int), typeof(MyViewCell), 300);
        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ImageWidth", typeof(int), typeof(MyViewCell), 300);

        public int ImageHeight
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(ImageHeightProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImageHeightProperty, value);
        }

       public int ImageWidth
       {
            get => (int)GetValue(ImageWidthProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImageWidthProperty, value);
       }

       public MyViewCell() {
           MediaImage = new Image
           {
               HeightRequest = ImageHeight,
               WidthRequest = ImageWidth

           };
           var frame = new Frame {
              Content = 'your components in a grid/stack'
           }
       View = frame;
      }
   }
```

Then you do the necessary changes when the binding context changes, e.g changing image sources, text content, etc:

```
 protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        MediaImage.HeightRequest = ImageHeight;
        MediaImage.WidthRequest = WidthRequest;
    };
```